# What is a good term for a percent (2%) being stored as 0.02 in a database?

Tags: database, terminology

I want to store `2%` in a database as `0.02`. This column was going to be called `percent_off`, but now I'm just wondering if math provides a better term for it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think math provides a better term, percent is the mathematical term. But 2 is the percent, not 0.02. "0.02 percent off" is 99.98% not 2%. "Discount" perhaps?

Comment: @Dan Yeh, that should probably be percent_of

Comment: I'd call it a "ratio", but i can think of 3 SE sites that this is more relevant on - math, English and programmers...

Comment: ... either ratio or factor. Maybe just 'discount'.

Answer (score 0):

Not convinced on this one, but perhaps quotient. I think it might be worth trying not to think of it as a percentage, but as a fraction, for want of a better way of describing it.

Or, depending on the application domain, that might give a better clue as to a good name.

Answer (score 0):

"Percent" is about as descriptive a value as "Number". It just means that some value was divided by 100, not what that value means in the context.

I doubt that you would create a column titled Number or String or Date, so why call it Percent?

It would be best if you use whatever the meaning of the percent is (discount, interest, quotient) for the name, and not just the type of the data.

Comment: I have a number 100, I need to store the `percent_off`, and the `static_discount`

Comment: `percent_off` sounds kinda ok, if it's the percent off the purchase price. Using just `off` as a name might not be clear (e.g. num_repeats is an ok name for a field that stores the number of repeats)

Answer (score 0):

How about `fraction`?  I wonder if `discount_of` might be seen as ambiguous: should a 3% discount be stored as 0.03 or as 0.97?